# T-SQL: Build New Table from Result Set

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

First off: total SQL newbie here. I unfortunately had this thrust on me on a deadline. :/ My apologies if this is a dumb question.

So I have a DB with a view that has various columns.  It has two columns I'm interested in: **UserID** and **Age**.

- **Age** stores the age of a report in days from the day it was created.
- **UserID** is the user that created the report.

The view lists all reports for a user.

We I need to do is create a new table/view from the existing view that lists each unique user, and then breaks down their total documents into various age groups.  So the columns would look something like:

User || # rprts <14 days || # rprts 14-17 days || # rprts 18-28 days || # rprts 29-44 days || # rprts 45+ days

I know I can get the set of all the users I want with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [UserID] FROM [DB].[dbo].[DB_View]
```

And I can run the following and get one row of what I want for the new table/view by hardcoding a UserID #:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

    [UserID],
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DB].[dbo].[DB_View] WHERE (Age < 14) AND UserID = '9999') AS "Less Than 14 Days",
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DB].[dbo].[DB_View] WHERE (Age BETWEEN 14 AND 17) AND UserID = '9999') AS "14 to 17 Days",
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DB].[dbo].[DB_View] WHERE (Age BETWEEN 18 AND 28) AND UserID = '9999') AS "18 to 28 Days",
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DB].[dbo].[DB_View] WHERE (Age BETWEEN 29 AND 44) AND UserID = '9999') AS "29 to 44 Days",
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DB].[dbo].[DB_View] WHERE (Age >= 45) AND UserID = '9999') AS "Over 45 Days"

FROM [DB].[dbo].[DB_View]
WHERE UserID = '9999'
```

The result set of users is about ~600 rows, and the view usually has about 6,000-15,000 rows.  My initial thought was just get my result set of users, then store each user to a parameter, and then pass that into the query where I've hardcoded a User ID.  Sadly, I can't even figure out the SQL to do that.  (And I'm guessing there's a much more efficient way to do this if you know your SQL....) I've seen stuff on using cursors and stuff, but I don't really understand it that well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right:

```
SELECT [UserID],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Age < 14 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Less Than 14 Days],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 14 AND 17 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [14 to 17 Days],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 18 AND 28 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [18 to 28 Days],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 29 AND 44 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [29 to 44 Days],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Age >= 45 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Over 45 Days]

FROM [DB].[dbo].[DB_View]
GROUP BY [UserID]
```

Comment: HOLY MOTHER OF GOD! YOU ARE AWESOME! :D  Seriously, thank you so, so much.  This works perfectly and runs in less than a second.

The CASE part makes sense (didn't know you could do that in SQL).

If it's not too much to ask, could you explain why you don't have to use a SELECT DISTINCT? I assume it has to do with GROUP BY, but I'm not super clear from a google search on the term.

Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, because the GROUP BY aggregates the rows by `UserID` so you will only get one row for each group at the other end (the fields in the GROUP BY clause and aggregated information for all rows that match the clause). To see GROUP BY in action another way, try `SELECT Age, COUNT(UserID) FROM DB.dbo.DB_View GROUP BY Age` - you should be able to see what it does.

Comment: As a side note, If you *only* want a single UserId (e.g. '9999') you don't actually need SELECT DISTINCT in your initial query. You could do it as subqueries like you had; you should notice all rows are the same, so a simple `TOP 1` would do.

Comment: Awesome, yeah, I see what you're saying.  Thank you so much for all your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple group by, with the CASE statement for conditional sums by age:

```
SELECT [UserID],
       SUM(case when Age < 14 then 1 else 0 end) AS "Less Than 14 Days",
       SUM(case when Age BETWEEN 14 AND 17 then 1 else 0 end) as "14 to 17 Days",
       SUM(case when Age BETWEEN 18 AND 28 then 1 else 0 end) as "18 to 28 Days",
       SUM(case when Age BETWEEN 29 AND 44 then 1 else 0 end) as "29 AND 44 Days",
       SUM(case when Age BETWEEN 29 AND 44 then 1 else 0 end) as "29 AND 44 Days",
       SUM(case when Age >= 45 then 1 else 0 end) as "Over 45 Days"
from [DB].[dbo].[DB_View] 
where  UserID = '9999'
group by userID
```